# django-social-auth obtain claimed id

Tags: python, django, openid

I'm trying to make an OpenId log in using [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) and I'm trying to get it work with [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/dev). Thing is, Steam's System is just give you a 64bits hash using the claimed_id and then use that to obtain the information using another API. My question is: How I get the claimed_id using the django-social-auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the claimed id was saved in the social_auth record as a uid.